# how to know window is open in qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have created two Main windows. How to know whether 2nd window is open in QT?

```
QMainWindow *window1 = new QMainWindow();

QMainWindow *window2 = new QMainWindow();
```

Now I have to find whther window2 is already opened in my one instance. How to know it

Comment: By "open" you mean visible / showing on the screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [visible property:](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#visible-prop)

```
if (window2->isVisible()) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: It is not working. As i want to close that window.. I am using these code:                                                                if(window2->isVisible()) window2->close();

Comment: You need to be more specific - **what** does not work? Is the window still showing?

Comment: Yes window is still showing

Comment: Then your issue is with `close()`, not with `isVisible()` - check out https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#close. What does `window2->close()` return? Did you override the closeEvent handler? You need to provide more code, ideally as an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 2):

use `QWidget#visible`: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#properties

```
if(window1-> isVisible()) {
  //...
}
```

Edited per comment below.

Comment: class QMainWindow’ has no member named ‘visible’
It is showing these error

Comment: You should use the `isVisible()` method to access the property

Comment: It is not working. As i want to close that window.. I am using these code but window is not closing: if(window2->isVisible()) window2->close()